# ApexCharts - Heatmap

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I really need your help to make my heatmap chart work when using my API through useEffect.

I'm creating a chart 24x7 where the y axis represent the days of the week and the x axis represent the hours of the day.

This is the graph I need:

https://yourimageshare.com/ib/PQJR2WIGvB

But when communicating with API, I'm not getting it right.

I have 3 values, "hora" which means "hour of the day", "quantidadeVenda" which means "amount of sales" and "chave" which means "day of the week".

I'm not really finding where to add all this information. I understand it works as x, y and z, but don't really know how to translate it into my code.

This is what I have right now, but it's not really working.

Please, I would really appreciate your help!

````
const data = {
    series: [
      {
        name: (valores ?? []).map((calor: any) => {
        return calor.chave;
      }),
        data: (valores.detalhamento ?? []).map((calor: any) => {
        return calor.quantidadeVenda;
      }),
      },
    ], 
    options: {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'heatmap',
        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        heatmap: {
          colorScale: {
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 20,
                color: '#ffc9b8',
              },
              {
                from: 20,
                to: 40,
                color: '#fcbba7',
              },
              {
                from: 40,
                to: 60,
                color: '#fcaf97',
              },
              {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: '#ffa327',
              },
              {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: '#ff9777',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      legend: {
        show: false,
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: (valores.detalhamento ?? []).map((calor: any) => {
        return calor.hora;
      }),
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: theme.palette.grey[isLight ? 800 : 300],
          },
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: theme.palette.grey[isLight ? 800 : 300],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  } as any;```
````